# Построение гистограммы по датам

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, seaborn

Помогите построить гистограмму показывающую сколько пользователей зарегестрировалось в 2017 году. И как построить гистограмму в которой будет отображено количество зарегестрировавшихся за 2 года (2016, 2017)? Буду благодарен за реализацию, как в Seaborn так и в Matplotlib. Столбец 'Reg_date' уже приведёy к формату datetime.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
[{'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 20, 'Country': 'USA', 'Reg_date': '2016-05-02'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 12, 'Country': 'Australia', 'Reg_date': '2016-12-26'},
 {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'France', 'Reg_date': '2017-09-27'},
 {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 58, 'Country': 'USA', 'Reg_date': '2016-08-19'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 79, 'Country': 'USA', 'Reg_date': '2017-11-07'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 38, 'Country': 'France', 'Reg_date': '2017-06-15'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 18, 'Country': 'Australia', 'Reg_date': '2017-02-21'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 49, 'Country': 'USA', 'Reg_date': '2018-01-05'},
 {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 43, 'Country': 'USA', 'Reg_date': '2017-05-11'},
 {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 60, 'Country': 'France', 'Reg_date': '2016-10-12'}])

df['Reg_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Reg_date'])
```

Comment: гистограмма нужна только по годам без разбивки по странам / полу?

Comment: Изменяя смысл вопроса, после того как на него были получены ответы - вы инвалидируете данные вам ответы. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте новый SO вопрос...

Comment: @MaxU прошу прощения. Впредь так и буду делать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [130]: df.groupby(df['Reg_date'].dt.year).size().plot.bar(rot=90, grid=True)
Out[130]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1a084134fd0>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> как отобразить число зарегестрировавшихся 2017-05, т.е. в конкретный
>   месяц конкретного года?

```
In [306]: df.query("Reg_date.dt.year == 2017")
Out[306]:
   Age    Country   Reg_date Sex
2   23     France 2017-09-27   m
4   79        USA 2017-11-07   f
5   38     France 2017-06-15   f
6   18  Australia 2017-02-21   f
8   43        USA 2017-05-11   m

In [307]: df.query("Reg_date.dt.year == 2017 and Reg_date.dt.month == 5")
Out[307]:
   Age Country   Reg_date Sex
8   43     USA 2017-05-11   m

In [310]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Reg_date', freq='MS')).size()
Out[310]:
Reg_date
2016-05-01    1
2016-06-01    0
2016-07-01    0
2016-08-01    1
2016-09-01    0
2016-10-01    1
2016-11-01    0
2016-12-01    1
2017-01-01    0
2017-02-01    1
2017-03-01    0
2017-04-01    0
2017-05-01    1
2017-06-01    1
2017-07-01    0
2017-08-01    0
2017-09-01    1
2017-10-01    0
2017-11-01    1
2017-12-01    0
2018-01-01    1
Freq: MS, dtype: int64
```

Comment: а как сделать запрос по годам и месяцам? К примеру, как отобразить число зарегестрировавшихся 2017-05, т.е. в конкретный месяц конкретного года?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЖук, вы определитесь какая гистограмма вам нужна ;)

Comment: ты лучший)
Никакой конкретно, просто изучаю возможности) 
Можно ли узнать топ-месяц в 2017ом?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЖук, что значит "топ-месяц"?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЖук - ни слова «спасибо» человеку, который вам помогает, ни принятие ответа, ни голос за ответ - только получать бесплатно?

Comment: @MarianD во-первых вы не знаете чем я был занят настолько, что не посещал данную страницу с тех пор, как был дан последний ответ. Во-вторых не знаете, НАСКОЛЬКО я благодарен MaxU. И из-за моего начального рейтинга мой голос пока не учитывается. Смешно, как вы залетели тут с критикой в мой адрес)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо! Предельно благодарен

Comment: @ЕвгенийЖук, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийЖук, теперь уже всё в порядке.